# Using DbContext SaveChanges with Transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, transactions, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

As MSDN [confirms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx), in EF 5 and on, the DbContext class is "a combination of the Unit-Of-Work and Repository patterns."  In the web applications I build, I tend to implement the Repository and Unit-Of-Work patterns on top of the existing DbContext class.  Lately, like many others out there, I've found that this is overkill in my scenario.  I am not worried about the underlying storage mechanism ever changing from SQL Server, and while I appreciate the benefits that unit testing would bring, I still have a lot to learn about it before actually implementing it in a live application.

Thus, my solution is to use the DbContext class directly as the Repository and Unit-Of-Work, and then use StructureMap to inject one instance per request to individual service classes, allowing them to do work on the context.  Then in my controllers, I inject each service I need and call the methods necessary by each action accordingly.  Also, each request is wrapped in a  transaction created off of the DbContext at the beginning of the request and either rolled back if any type of exception occurred (whether it be an EF error or application error) or committed if all is well.  A sample code scenario is below.

*This sample uses the Territory and Shipper tables from the Northwind sample database.  In this sample admin controller, a territory and a shipper are being added at the same time.*

**Controller**

```
public class AdminController : Controller 
{
    private readonly TerritoryService _territoryService;
    private readonly ShipperService _shipperService;

    public AdminController(TerritoryService territoryService, ShipperService shipperService)
    {
        _territoryService = territoryService;
        _shipperService = shipperService;
    }

    // all other actions omitted...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(AdminInsertViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        var newTerritory = // omitted code to map from viewModel
        var newShipper = // omitted code to map from viewModel

        _territoryService.Insert(newTerritory);
        _shipperService.Insert(newShipper);

        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
    }
}
```

**Territory Service**

```
public class TerritoryService
{
    private readonly NorthwindDbContext _dbContext;

    public TerritoryService(NorthwindDbContext dbContext) 
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Insert(Territory territory)
    {
        _dbContext.Territories.Add(territory);
    }
}
```

**Shipper Service**

```
public class ShipperService
{
    private readonly NorthwindDbContext _dbContext;

    public ShipperService(NorthwindDbContext dbContext) 
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Insert(Shipper shipper)
    {
        _dbContext.Shippers.Add(shipper);
    }
}
```

**Creation of Transaction on Application_BeginRequest()**

```
// _dbContext is an injected instance per request just like in services
HttpContext.Items["_Transaction"] = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

**Rollback or Commit of Transaction on Application_EndRequest**

```
var transaction = (DbContextTransaction)HttpContext.Items["_Transaction"];

if (HttpContext.Items["_Error"] != null) // populated on Application_Error() in global
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
else
{
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Now this all seems to work well, but the only question I have now is where is it best to call the `SaveChanges()` function on the DbContext?  Should I call it in each Service layer method?

```
public class TerritoryService
{
    // omitted code minus changes to Insert() method below

    public void Insert(Territory territory)
    {
        _dbContext.Territories.Add(territory);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();  // <== Call it here?
    }
}

public class ShipperService
{
    // omitted code minus changes to Insert() method below

    public void Insert(Shipper shipper)
    {
        _dbContext.Shippers.Add(shipper);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();  // <== Call it here?
    }
}
```

Or should I leave the service class Insert() methods as is and just call SaveChanges() right before the transaction is committed?

```
var transaction = (DbContextTransaction)HttpContext.Items["_Transaction"];

// HttpContext.Items["_Error"] populated on Application_Error() in global
if (HttpContext.Items["_Error"] != null) 
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
else
{
    // _dbContext is an injected instance per request just like in services
    _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // <== Call it here?
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Is either way okay?  Is it safe to call SaveChanges() more than once since it is wrapped in a transaction?  Are there any issues I may run into by doing so?  Or is it best to call SaveChanges() just once right before the transaction is actually committed?  I personally would rather just call it at the end right before the transaction is committed, but I want to be sure I am not missing any gotcha's with transactions or doing something wrong?  If you read this far, thanks for taking the time to help.  I know this was a long question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would call `SaveChanges()` when it's time to commit a single, atomic persistence operation.  Since your services don't really know about each other or depend on each other, internally they have no way to guarantee one or the other is going to commit the changes.  So in this setup I imagine they would *each* have to commit their changes.

This of course leads to the problem that these operations might not be individually atomic.  Consider this scenario:

```
_territoryService.Insert(newTerritory);  // success
_shipperService.Insert(newShipper);  // error
```

In this case you've partially committed the data, leaving the system in a bit of an unknown state.

Which object in this scenario is in control over the atomicity of the operation?  In web applications I think that's *usually* the controller.  The operation, after all, is the request made by the user.  In *most* scenarios (there are exceptions, of course) I imagine one would expect the entire request to succeed or fail.

If this is the case and your atomicity belongs at the request level then what I would recommend is getting the `DbContext` from the IoC container at the controller level and passing it to the services.  (They already require it on their constructors, so not a big change there.)  Those services can operate on the context, but never *commit* the context.  The consuming code (the controller) can then commit it (or roll it back, or abandon it, etc.) once all of the services have completed their operations.

While different business objects, services, etc. should each internally maintain their own logic, I find that usually the objects which own the atomicity of operations are at the application level, governed by the business processes being invoked by the users.

Comment: I had originally thought to do that, but then wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the Service layer if now you can access any DbSet<T> you want on the context without having to use the Service layer.  I was hoping to isolate interaction with the context to the service layers if possible to keep the controllers clean.  Or am I complicating this?

Comment: @ryanulit: I think the services in this case aren't really services, they're more like repositories.  A service is usually something which itself exposes atomic business operations and can be replaced with, for example, a web service implementation.  What you have here look more like repositories, which would logically hang off of a unit of work.  In this case, the `DbContext` is that unit of work.  Perhaps you can even create a wrapper for `DbContext` which internally hosts instances of these repositories, effectively replicating the pattern you thought was overkill :)

Comment: I agree that they look like repositories in this simplified scenario, but they could also include business logic in between retrieving and/or updating the database. Also, wouldn't the transaction per request setup I have allow the operation to be atomic since the changes won't actually get written to the database unless everything succeeds?

Comment: @ryanulit: What sort of business logic? There could be other patterns to fit that. A transaction per request may work just as well, sure. Think of it like a roundabout way of a unit of work, where as long as the underlying services participate in a transaction scope then it should work. Provided, of course, that Step 2 of the process doesn't need information committed from Step 1 of the process, because Step 2's `DbContext` won't have it. (Unless the IoC returns the same instance of the `DbContext`? This is starting to sound more complex and less stable than the pattern you were avoiding...)

Comment: Yes, the IoC container is setup to return the same instance of the DbContext.  This is not my best example, but some extra bus. logic could be something like changing the active status of an entity to true or false because a certain date has passed.  It's possible there may be better patterns for this, as I've been trying to wrap my head around all the different layers/patterns out there, but I guess my most important question here is what kind of trouble I could get into, if any, with using save changes together with transactions?

Comment: This is a common approach (creating an Ambient transaction for the Http Context) and I wouldn't think it is a bad approach and will ensure your commits are transactional, even if you call SaveChanges 10 times.  The main issue is when you depend on getting some db-generated ID from a SaveChanges, before calling another service method.  In such cases, it may be best to leverage a GUID that is generated by the application, instead of relying on the DB to generated IDs.  I have started to believe that abstracting an ORM such as EF or Nhibernate is pointless and leads to problems down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically creating a repository here, rather than a service.

To answer your question you could just ask yourself another question. "How will I be using this functionality?"

You're adding a couple of records, removing some records, updating some records. We could say that you're calling your various methods about 30 times. If you call SaveChanges 30 times you're making 30 round-trips to the database, causing a lot of traffic and overhead which COULD be avoided.

I usually recommend doing as few database round-trips as possible, and limit the amount of calls to SaveChanges(). Therefore I recommend that you add a Save() method to your repository/service layer and call it in the layer which calls your repository/service layer.

Unless it is absolutely required to save something before doing something else you shouldn't call it 30 times. You should call it 1 single time. If it is necessary to save something before doing something else you could still call SaveChanges in that absolute moment of requirement in the layer calling your repository/service layer.

**Summary/TL;DR:** Make a Save() method in your repository/service layer instead of calling SaveChanges() in each repository/service method. This will boost your performance and spare you the unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I actually got rid of my own repository layer to use the repository layer of DbSet<T> already within the DbContext class.  I think I would be right back where I started if I went this route.

Comment: @ryanulit You'd still achieve your goal of isolating context communication, and you'd gain an increase in performance if you use the pattern well. You have already mentioned your alternative.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding.  Would you be able to provide a code example of this to help me?

Comment: @ryanulit You'd basically just make a Save() call after queueing up your service layer methods. Imagine you're adding five territories, rather than having each Insert() call SaveChanges() you'd just call a Save() method on your service from the consuming code, i.e. your controller. This Save() method will be responsible of calling a save method on your underlying data storage, i.e. your context.